# Fetching only changed SQL result from server

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, caching

My iOS application fetches some photos, tags and comments from web server. I want it to fetch only changed or new added data. I don't want it to fetch repeated data again and again.
I use SDWebImage for pictures. But text are based on SQL text. 
How could I understand the result of the SQL is changed or not? What kind of technique
should I use? 
Is there a third party library for client side SQL catching?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not iOS related question technically. You should query always with the last queried timestamp.

Like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE last_modified > last_queried_timestamp;
```

*last_modified* field should store the timestamp of the last modification date or the timestamp of creation and the *last_queried_timestamp* parameter is the timestamp of the last date when you queried from the server.

This way you will not get twice the same changes.
(Unless you want it)

Comment: The problem is more than one user could do same SQL request. (I agree with you this is not directly related to iOS. But may be there could be an iOS 3rd party library)

Comment: If you handle this only in client side (with a 3rd party library) the performance will not be the best. I kept in mind reducing the network traffic and the work on the client.

Comment: I'm using Amazon RDB (mysql) as database. Amazonon RDB would handle caching at server side.

Comment: It solves some performance, but the responses from the server will be big (but fast because of caching) and the client has to work a lot.